# How to have Nginx serve multiple HTML files for my very basic website

Tags: nginx

I can't seem to figure this out. I understand the basics of HTML but I am an absolute beginner using Nginx.

I managed to create a one page website with my own URL that I self host on Vultr. My problem is I can't figure out how to add a second page.

Typing [www.jacobblog.com](http://www.jacobblog.com) works perfectly and returns the index.html file I have placed at
/var/www/mysite/

I have created a file info.html in the same directory /var/www/mysite/ and want it to show up when I type [www.jacobblog.com/info](http://www.jacobblog.com/info)

I have tried this based on a similar question that was asked on the forum. As I said before jacobblog.com returns the index.html file but jacobblog.com/info only returns error 404.

The file I created in /etc/nginx/sites-available looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name jacobblog.com ;
        root /var/www/mysite ;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html ;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
        }

        location = /info {
                 rewrite ^ /info.html last;
        }
        
        
       
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the .html ending bothers you, but you can use alias

```
location =/info {
    default_type "text/html";
    alias /var/www/mysite/info.html;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to just add .html! I'm very new at this and what you suggested works perfectly. Thank you!